# HTML mailer has behaving badly

Tags: html, gmail, html-email

This is probably the simplest thing to fix, but I can't seem to find a solution for this.

Taking the following HTML, when I create an OFT from the HTML, and send a mail to my Gmail account, where ever there's an image, there's a space.

I have search far and wide for a solution to this, but Gmail keeps stripping out the inline styles, and attaching a  in the header of the HTML template gets ignored as well.

The HTML, very simple ( images omited for security reasons, the all point to a CDN ):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

    <center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="636" style="margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" valign="top"><img alt="" src="someimage1.gif" style="display: block;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" valign="top"><img alt="" src="someimage2.gif" style="display: block !important;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="18" valign="top" align="center" style="vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#c4dae4" style="font-family: Arial; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
                    <p><strong>Dear {name}</strong></p>
                </td>
                <td width="18" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="18" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top" height="673" width="600"><img alt="" src="someimage3.gif" style="display: block !important;" /></td>
                <td width="18" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried every possible solution, as stated, from display: block to line-height: 50%; to ensuring that the  tags don't have spacing.

Is there something I'm missing here? Something I'm obviously not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

it looks fine, but GMail is weird about doctypes. Try this one, hopefully it works out.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`